# Receive data with jquery ajax json to HTML from spring rest api

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, ajaxform

I'm new to jquery/spring, I've created simple rest api service which is working I checked it in Postman. I would like to ask how to receive json data in HTML file with jQuery ajax.
Does HTML file must be in Service file structure?

I was trying sth like this but nothing happend.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/notes"
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
       $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
    });
});
```

```html
<p class="id">Id: </p>
<p class="content">content: </p>
```

Comment: _"nothing happend"_ <- that's unlikely. Check you browser console, including the _Network_ tab

Comment: Good point, I got this error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/notes' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I solve this by adding @CrossOrigin to RestController but then, nothing happend in console and still not working.

Comment: So, how about that _Network_ console?